# How can I find all regular expressions in a string?

Tags: regex, preg-replace

I'm looking to use a regular expression, to find regular expressions in a block of content.

**Use case:** We'd like to have a block of content, and highlight all regular expressions that are in that content.

e.g., we want to change this:

```
This is some (.*) content the belongs to [w+]
```

To this:

```
This is some <span class="regex">(.*)</span> content the belongs to <span class="regex">[w+]</span>
```

Has anybody seen a way to achieve this?

Comment: Technically, nearly all strings are regex. You should maybe refine your requirement.

Comment: Plese provide some real world input strings and what you want to have matched. Additionally, a programming language or Editor would be nice as well as there are different engines/flavours (i.e. what is supported, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

As Jérémie B said in a comment, you'll have to "refine your requirement".

If you could limit the REs and only allow simple ones, something like this may get you on your way:

```
((?:\([^)]*[.*?[\]]*\)|\\[wdsb0nfrtv]|\[[^]]*\])(?:\?|\*|\+|\{\d+(?:,\d+)?\})?)
```

It basically handles three types of REs.

1. A group - at least one of the characters `.*?[]^` enclosed in parenthesis `()`.
2. Character classes - anything enclosed in brackets `[]`.
3. A "shorthand" character class e.g. `\w`.

Optionally followed by a quantifier.

See [this example at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/aM8lQ7/1).

It's very crude, but may be of help to you.

Regards.